# Angular 5 : Position a button half outside mat dialog

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I want dialog box to have a close button which is on top right corner of dialog(half inside/half out) like the one in image :

I am able to achieve this using absolute positioning but that is not a feasible option.

I want to position the button with reference to dialog, I also tried using `float:right` and giving `margin-top` in negative but the other half is hidden even on setting `z-index` to more than 1000.

```
<button mat-mini-fab style="cursor:pointer;position:absolute;top:420px;left:900px">
<i class="material-icons" (click)="close()">close</i>
</button>
```

[image] (Courtesy :codota.com).

Comment: Can you share the stackblitz

Comment: Hi @PrashantPimpale https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxxngpbnmlxj is from angular's official documentation.All I need is a close button added to this on top right corner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

where is the button positioned inside the dialog html ? you shouldn't need to use values like `900px` and `420px`. Make it positioned absolute relative the the dialog container ( the ' white ' container )  and just use `top:0;right:0`; and `translate(50%,-50%)` .

It should position it as you want. See quick example below

```css
.dialog {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="dialog">
<button>X</button>
</div>
```

also check stackblitz -> [dialog stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xe2z3l) .
I added a class to the dialog panel ( 'my-dialog' in the component file ) and added css in the global style file as the dialog container/ dialog panel are not accessible from the component.

Comment: This does not work. It displays the button at corner of the page instead of the dialog.
I am opening my dialog through another ts file as its done in https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxxngpbnmlxj

Comment: I saw the stackblitz and things work properly but due to complex nature of my local code I am still not able to make it  work but I am sure I will be able to get it working in some time with the help of your code. Thanks!

Comment: Just be sure you add the button in the dialog html outside any other containers. And then write the css  in the global css file. Otherwise the styles won't have any effect on the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You should position the button within the dialog which it should close:

```
<dialog-component>
   Content... content.. content...

   <button mat-mini-fab class="close-dialog-btn">
     <i class="material-icons" (click)="close()">close</i>
   </button>
</dialog-component>
```

Assuming, the `dialog-component` has a `position` of `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`, you can position the button with the following CSS:

```
.close-dialog-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The `right/top` attributes will position the button in the upper right corner. The `transform` attibute will shift it half of its own width up/sideways.

Also, make sure there is no padding directly on the dialog-element, otherwise you may have to adjust the `top/right`-attributes to compensate that padding.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but in my attempt to use this solution, the styled control appears at the top right of the entire window, not the top right of the open modal dialog.